# Reporting Services (SSRS) cuts the name of the exported file

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS 2016 13.0.4001.0
I have a report. Report name: "6.0 Reports"
I export to excel and file name is "6.xlsx"
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to remove the dot from report name, maybe that affects the file name

Comment: But i need dot. Without dot works.

Comment: I assume that this is an SSRS limitation

Comment: I tried to move dot to first position. Reportname ".60 Reports", exported file name "xlsx" :) Bug?

Comment: Without extension.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
Symbol from MS Word: "ꓸ".

Report name: "6ꓸ1 Reports" => export to excel filename "6ꓸ1 Reports.xlsx"
```

[symbol from ms word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxqqP.jpg)
[export file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnmwr.jpg)